# How to get the value inside a primitive M

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

```
showInfoCursor, err := collection.Aggregate(context.TODO(), mongo.Pipeline{unwindStage, groupStage})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    var showsWithInfo []bson.M
    if err = showInfoCursor.All(context.TODO(), &showsWithInfo); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

I'm iterating the showsWithInfo array. And each **bson.M** contains a **primitive M** type value for a particular key. I've tried to convert it to a struct, but it was no successful.

```
map[operatorId:1 channel: XYZ]
```

This is what I got once I print the value of that **primitive M**.
I need to get those two values from that. (operatorId, channel)

Answer (score 4):

[`bson.M`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#M) is a type alias to `primitive.M`:

```
type M = primitive.M
```

And [`primitive.M`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.4.3/bson/primitive#M) is a "simple" map:

```
type M map[string]interface{}
```

So you may index the value as you would any maps:

```
m := primitive.M{
    "operatorId": 1,
    "channel":    "XYZ",
}
fmt.Println(m)

fmt.Println("Operator ID:", m["operatorId"])
fmt.Println("Channel:", m["channel"])
```

This outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UePrrRewQmI)):

```
map[channel:XYZ operatorId:1]
Operator ID: 1
Channel: XYZ
```